# Not able to deploy the django app on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When trying to deploy my django app using eb deploy I am getting the following error. It is totally unseful and does not let me knwo what to do. Please help.

I am following the tutorial here : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

```
 sh-3.2# eb deploy
    Creating application version archive "app-ca0a-151123_205119".
    Uploading learningsite/app-ca0a-151123_205119.zip to S3. This may take a while.
    Upload Complete.
    INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
    INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
    ERROR: Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
    ERROR: [Instance: i-18ee63c1] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. 
    Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
    INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
    ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-18ee63c1'. Aborting the operation.
    ERROR: Failed to deploy application.                                


ERROR: Failed to deploy application.
sh-3.2#
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to EB! You'll get plenty of hard to decrypt error messages.

The important line here is `ERROR: Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.` There is something wrong with your requirements.txt file and EB is not able to install.

Locally if you run `pip install -r requirements.txt` you might be able to see the error.

Comment: Thanks. When I go onto AWS Dashboard on Elastic Beanstalk the error is this: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version. Could you help me with the error please?

Comment: That error you see there really means very little - it's just saying that something went wrong in the last deployment. You got the clue in the deploy message that it errored on the requirements.txt. Running `eb logs` will get you even more info. What does your requirements.txt look like?

Comment: altgraph==0.10.2
awsebcli==3.5.6
backports-abc==0.4
backports.ssl-match-hostname==3.4.0.2
bdist-mpkg==0.5.0
blessed==1.9.5
bonjour-py==0.3
botocore==1.3.8
cement==2.4.0
certifi==2015.11.20
colorama==0.3.3
-e git://github.com/django/django.git@6ca163d7cc451fafd3015fa2ee735d5377fa3065#egg=Django-dev
docker-py==1.1.0
dockerpty==0.3.4
docopt==0.6.2
docutils==0.12
Feedjack==15.5.1
feedparser==5.2.1
jmespath==0.9.0
macholib==1.5.1
matplotlib==1.3.1
modulegraph==0.10.4
nltk==3.1
nose==1.3.7
numpy==1.8.0rc1

Comment: pathspec==0.3.3
py2app==0.7.3
pyasn1==0.1.9
pyobjc-core==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Accounts==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-AppleScriptObjC==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Automator==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CFNetwork==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Cocoa==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Collaboration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreData==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreLocation==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-CoreText==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-DictionaryServices==2.5.1

Comment: pyobjc-framework-EventKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ExceptionHandling==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-FSEvents==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InputMethodKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstallerPlugins==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-InstantMessage==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LatentSemanticMapping==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-LaunchServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Message==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-OpenDirectory==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PreferencePanes==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-PubSub==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-QTKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Quartz==2.5.1

Comment: pyobjc-framework-ScreenSaver==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ScriptingBridge==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SearchKit==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-ServiceManagement==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-Social==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SyncServices==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-SystemConfiguration==2.5.1
pyobjc-framework-WebKit==2.5.1
pyOpenSSL==0.13.1
pyparsing==2.0.1
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2013.7
PyYAML==3.11
requests==2.6.2
rsa==3.2.3
scipy==0.13.0b1
singledispatch==3.4.0.3
six==1.4.1
texttable==0.8.4
tornado==4.3
wcwidth==0.1.5
websocket-client==0.34.0
wheel==0.26.0
xattr==0.6.4
zope.interface==4.1.1

Comment: I did not know how to show you the requirements.txt file so pasted here.

Comment: are you able to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` on your local project without error?

Comment: earlier i did not use the virtualenv while working on the project. Could that have been the issue?